# Rails 3 on windows - server is frozen (does not respond) on Ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In the process of upgrading an application to Rails3, I encountered a problem which I isolated in a new application with one controller#action: dummies#index. 
The issue: I start my server, send a request to the action, and nothing seems to happen.
The log file has this line and nothing after it:

```
Started GET "/dummies" for 127.0.0.1 at Sun Nov 14 14:49:22 -0800 2010
```

If I change to Ruby 1.9.2, it works. However my 1.9.2 interpreter crashes sometimes when it accesses MySQL for some reason (that's a topic for a different question), and I couldn't find a compiled ruby-debug19 for windows, so I'd like to stay with 1.8.7.

If I change the adapter to Sqlite3, it works. So my guess is my problem is with MySQL.

From within rails console, I have no problem to access the database through a model object (with MySQL and Ruby 1.8.7).

Any thoughts on how to isolate the problem further?

I'm working on Windows 7, MySQL 5.1.51, mysql2 gem (0.2.6).

Here is the result of bundle list, just in case:

```
  * abstract (1.0.0)
  * actionmailer (3.0.1)
  * actionpack (3.0.1)
  * activemodel (3.0.1)
  * activerecord (3.0.1)
  * activeresource (3.0.1)
  * activesupport (3.0.1)
  * arel (1.0.1)
  * builder (2.1.2)
  * bundler (1.0.5)
  * erubis (2.6.6)
  * i18n (0.4.2)
  * mail (2.2.9)
  * mime-types (1.16)
  * mysql2 (0.2.6)
  * polyglot (0.3.1)
  * rack (1.2.1)
  * rack-mount (0.6.13)
  * rack-test (0.5.6)
  * rails (3.0.1)
  * railties (3.0.1)
  * rake (0.8.7)
  * sqlite3-ruby (1.3.1)
  * thor (0.14.4)
  * treetop (1.4.8)
  * tzinfo (0.3.23)
```

Thanks,
Amit

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue on OS X, and changing the gem to `ruby-mysql` instead of `mysql` did it for me. :)